# Why can my infix-to-postfix operator not produce a correct result?

Tags: pstricks

Why does

```
\pstGeonode(!{15/sqrt(25)} I2P 45 PtoC){B}
```

**NOT** produce the same output as

```
\pstGeonode(!15 25 sqrt div 45 PtoC){A}
```

where

```
\pstVerb{/I2P {exec AlgParser cvx exec} def}%
```

?

### Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}


\begin{document}

\pstVerb{/I2P {exec AlgParser cvx exec} def}%

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
\pstGeonode(!15 25 sqrt div 45 PtoC){A}
\psarc[linecolor=blue](0,0){3}{0}{90}
\end{pspicture}
%
\hspace{1cm}
%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
\pstGeonode(!{15/sqrt(25)} I2P 45 PtoC){B}
\psarc[linecolor=blue](0,0){3}{0}{90}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently it was my old problem where I forgot to enclose the expression with `()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question defines the PostScript operator `I2P`:

```postscript
/I2P {exec AlgParser cvx exec} def
```

And `I2P` gets a procedure as argument that gets executed (`exec`):

```
{25/sqrt(25)}
```

This is wrong, because the expression inside the curly braces are the infix
expression for `AlgParser` and *not* PostScript code. As far as I can see, `AlgParser` expects a PostScript string instead and the string is not executed:

```postscript
/I2P {AlgParser cvx exec} def
(25/sqrt(25)) I2P
```

The latter expression is put inside `\pstGeonode`:

```tex
\pstGeonode(...){B}
```

The argument is delimited by parentheses, however the infix expression also contains parentheses, causing trouble for TeX's argument parsing.
The correct way, adding curly braces:

```
\pstGeonode({...}){B}
```

does not work because of a bug in `\Pst@Geonode@ii` in file `pst-eucl.tex`:

```
\def\Pst@Geonode@ii(#1)#2{%
  \pnode(#1){#2}
  ....
}
```

TeX strips the curly braces of `#1` and passes the argument as macro argument that is again delimited by parentheses. Thus `\Pst@Geonode@ii` needs to be fixed:

```
\def\Pst@Geonode@ii(#1)#2{%
  \pnode({#1}){#2}% curly braces around #1 and line end removed
  ...
}
```

Without fixing (see below) a workaround can be used in this case:

A PostScript string can also be given as hexadecimal string with angle brackets.
If pdfTeX is used (regardless of mode), then the expandable `\pdfescapehex` can be used, or `\pdf@escapehex` of package `pdftexcmds` that also supports LuaTeX:

```
\pstGeonode(! <\pdfescapehex{15/sqrt(25)}> I2P 45 PtoC){B}
```

Alternatively the parentheses can be hidden inside a macro, e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\firstofone}[1]{#1}
\pstGeonode(! \firstofone{(15/sqrt(25))} I2P 45 PtoC){B}
```

Example file:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\pstVerb{/I2P {AlgParser cvx exec} def}%

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
\pstGeonode(!15 25 sqrt div 45 PtoC){A}
\psarc[linecolor=blue](0,0){3}{0}{90}  
\end{pspicture}
%
\hspace{1cm}
%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
\pstGeonode(! <\pdfescapehex{15/sqrt(25)}> I2P 45 PtoC){B}
\psarc[linecolor=blue](0,0){3}{0}{90}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Fixing `\Pst@Geonode@ii`:**

```
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Pst@Geonode@ii}{\pnode(#1)}{\pnode({#1})}{}{}
\makeatother

% then curly braces can be used to hide the inner parentheses:
\pstGeonode({! (15/sqrt(25)) I2P 45 PtoC}){B}
```

Comment: `\pstGeonode(!{(15/sqrt(25))} I2P 45 PtoC){B}` is the simplest one.

Comment: @WeirdstressFunction: Except that this does not work, because the added curly braces do not disappear in the PostScript code. TeX only removes one level of curly braces when reading an argument, if the curly braces surround the argument.

Comment: It will work if `\pstVerb{/I2P {exec AlgParser cvx exec} def}`.

Comment: @WeirdstressFunction: Then the curly braces generate a procedure with a literal string. `exec` calls the procedure (removes the curly braces) and pushes the literal string back on the stack because literal objects cannot be executed. Also the parentheses around the expression to make a PostScript string are mandatory for this scenario.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the explanation. :-)